# How do I change this sql statement to only select the first from each ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have the below code to select from a database, however, I only want the first record for each unique ID. Is there a way to change the SQL to achieve this?

```
SELECT       
        [CARL_Property].ID
        ,[PrDoorNum]
        ,[PrAddress1]
        ,[PrAddress2]
        ,[PrAddress3]
        ,[PrAddress4]
        ,[PrPostcode]
        ,[PrRent]
        ,[PrAgreedRent]
        ,[PrCommence]
        ,[PrEnd]
        ,[PrAvailable]
        ,[PrGrossIncome]
        ,[PrCouncilTax]
        ,[PrInventoryFee]
        ,[PrLetFee]
        ,[PrReletFee]
        ,[PrDateWithdrawn]
        ,[Rent Review]
        ,CARL_Owners.OwForenames
        ,CARL_Owners.OwSurname
        ,CARL_Property_List.[ID]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PrId]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PLBedrooms]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PlRooms]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PlBathrooms]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PlReceptions]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PlDeposit]
        ,CARL_Tenant_Contacts.[Tenant Name]
        ,CARL_New_Tenants.[TnLeaseperiod]
        ,CARL_Property_List.[PlAdvertising]
        ,[CARL_Property_Memos].[PrNotes]
        ,[CARL_Safety].[PrGasInsp]
        from dbo.CARL_Property Join dbo.[CARL_Property_Memos] on CARL_Property.ID=CARL_Property_Memos.PrID Join dbo.CARL_Owners on CARL_Owners.ID=CARL_Property.OwID Join dbo.CARL_PROPERTY_LIST ON dbo.CARL_PROPERTY.ID=dbo.CARL_PROPERTY_LIST.PrId Join dbo.[CARL_New_Tenants] ON CARL_New_Tenants.PrId=CARL_Property.ID JOIN CARL_Tenant_Contacts ON CARL_New_Tenants.ID = CARL_Tenant_Contacts.TnID Join [dbo].[CARL_Safety] On dbo.CARL_Property.ID=dbo.CARL_Safety.PrID
```

The result is as seen below.

[image]

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems to me that there is some kind of multiplicity within your table joins. I would recommend to analyze further deeper the query or the FK definitions. Otherwise, you could just use a SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY the columns you want to be "unique"

Comment: This is super simple using ROW_NUMBER. You just need to define what means "first". By definition a table is an unordered set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines I think is what you are looking for. Also, notice that I used aliases in your main query. It makes this a lot simpler to work with and reduces the amount of typing by a LOT.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    SELECT       
        cp.ID
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cp.ID order by pl.ID) as RowNum --order by whatever column defines "first"
        , [PrDoorNum]
        , [PrAddress1]
        , [PrAddress2]
        , [PrAddress3]
        , [PrAddress4]
        , [PrPostcode]
        , [PrRent]
        , [PrAgreedRent]
        , [PrCommence]
        , [PrEnd]
        , [PrAvailable]
        , [PrGrossIncome]
        , [PrCouncilTax]
        , [PrInventoryFee]
        , [PrLetFee]
        , [PrReletFee]
        , [PrDateWithdrawn]
        , [Rent Review]
        , o.OwForenames
        , o.OwSurname
        , pl.[ID] as PL_ID
        , pl.[PrId]
        , pl.[PLBedrooms]
        , pl.[PlRooms]
        , pl.[PlBathrooms]
        , pl.[PlReceptions]
        , pl.[PlDeposit]
        , tc.[Tenant Name]
        , nt.[TnLeaseperiod]
        , pl.[PlAdvertising]
        , pm.[PrNotes]
        , cs.[PrGasInsp]
    from dbo.CARL_Property p
    Join dbo.[CARL_Property_Memos] pm on p.ID = pm.PrID 
    Join dbo.CARL_Owners o on o.ID = p.OwID 
    Join dbo.CARL_PROPERTY_LIST pl ON p.ID = pl.PrId 
    Join dbo.[CARL_New_Tenants] nt ON nt.PrId = p.ID 
    JOIN CARL_Tenant_Contacts tc ON nt.ID = tc.TnID 
    Join [dbo].[CARL_Safety] cs On p.ID = cs.PrID
)

select *
from SortedResults
where RowNum = 1
order by ID
```

Comment: Perfect, with a few changes, I managed to make this work, you're a star.